# Integrate django model with legacy db

Tags: sql-server, django, python-3.x, django-models

I understand that Django Model is pretty fussy when it comes to the absence of a primary key.

I have a legacy database (SQL Server) that I am connecting too (it is not the default one), and in that I have a database.view which I am supposed access. However, the issue is that the view does not have any primary key.

How do i enable django to query from that table without being able to modify the schema?

Here is what I did:

I created a ReadOnlyModel and got my other django model to subclass it. This was done because I wanted to bypass the django's need for PK (evidently it did work, but threw another error - see below)

```
class ReadOnlyModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

I created an ActiveObjectManager for Django to know which database to point too. The reason i used this over a router is because the router would work best if I was creating two seperate applications in the same repo. However, I am using one application:

```
class Db2ActiveObjectManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(Db2ActiveObjectManager, self).get_queryset()
        if hasattr(self.model, 'use_db'):
            qs = qs.using(self.model.use_db)
        return qs
```

Below is a sample model from the Db2:

```
class modelA(ReadOnlyModel):
    use_db = 'db2'
    objects = Db2ActiveObjectManager()
    col1 = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=256)
    col2 = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=1024)
    col3 = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=256)
    col4 = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    col5 = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    col6 = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'db2.someTable'

    @classmethod
    def methodA(cls):
        try:
            filter_condition = {}
            return cls.objects.filter(**filter_condition)
        except Exception as e:
            raise ValueError("Invalid input")

    @classmethod
    def methodB(cls):
        try:
            return cls.objects.raw('SQL Query Here')
            # cursor = connection.cursor()
            # cursor.execute('SQL Query Here')
            # field_names = [field[0].lower() for field in cursor.description]
            # nt_result = namedtuple('Result', field_names)
            # return [nt_result(*row) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
        except Exception as e:
            raise
```

So far my current setup is throwing the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'api_readonlymodel'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I seen many developers on stackoverflow re-iterating that we need to add a pk to the table/view. But i cannot make any changes to that view. I am pretty sure that there is a work around, but no matter what I have tried so far, nothing seems to work out for me yet.

Either I get the above error^ or I get an error saying that no valid column called id is found, or I get an error stating that I need a PK...

Thanks for the help

Comment: I believe the "Invalid object name" error means that the table you are trying to access (api_readonlymodel) does not exist. I have worked on a legacy database before and defined a column in my model as the primary key even though it is not in the database, it works fine when you basically have a read-only model

Comment: Yes the ReadOnlyModel does not have a table. I mimic the concept from another stackoverflow post. If you defined the column as a pk, wouldnt it affect future operations when you get unique or sort or other operations hence giving funky results?

Comment: Sorting should be fine as it is on a column basis. SQL Server supports distinct (unique) queries so I don't think that would be an issue either

Comment: But you are correct: using a non-unique column as a "primary key" will have some funky behaviour in Django, I would recommend having some good tests

Comment: I guess as long as i am only performing read only function, i can put the primary key tag to a random column. I will try it out and see if it works for me. Cheers